# Laravel 5.2 Socialite Retrieve Null Email

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

i'm new to Laravel and i'm trying to make a social auth.
I have seen some tutorials and I've got to retrieve user id, profile pic and name from Facebook. My problem is the email, it comes null.

My current object is this:

```
User {#195 ▼
  +token: "EAACYY1xBrzcBAO9KZAjZAZAZBQHWhbtZAb9lIXvH9Y6miRUiABImupk3ZCzHRxy2ZBxc9DU8f1ZAcrw0NEVMmy3GOQMSSyrmDTvMPyREvGm4pA1Ok6zI85LxES4Huy2ZCsxIUr2ISbLreLIv1ZACItUUoqqAnvVPyR4s0ZD"
  +id: "989087311199546"
  +nickname: null
  +name: "MyName"
  +email: null
  +avatar: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/mypicturecode/picture?type=normal"
  +"user": array:2 [▼
    "name" => "MyName"
    "id" => "MyId"
  ]
}
```

and my controller is:

```
class FacebookController extends Controller
{
   public function facebook()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')
            ->scopes(['email'])->redirect();
    }
    public function callback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::with('facebook')->user();

        return dd($user);
        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

I recently discovered something. I have **"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"** in my composer to avoid the **cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)** error. When the guzzle 4.0 is installed, Laravel Socialite returns to the 2.0.4 version. Looks like the 2.0.18 version deals with the email and first_name/last_name problem. The problem is that when guzzle 4.0 is installed, it requires the socialite 2.0.4

Comment: Did you try another Facebook?

Comment: Yes, i tried at least 3 different facebook accounts

Answer (score 2):

To receive the email from your Facebook profile, you need to change the "email permission" from "standard access" to "advanced access".

```
Link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app-id>/app-review/permissions/
```

Once you save permission, you will start receiving the email in the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook users can register using a phone number instead of an email address. This means that facebook does not have an email address for that user.

And you might have own privacy policy.

Have a look at this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email

Comment: I tested with several emails from people who signed up in facebook with emails and my Facebook Application have the checkbox to retrieve the user email information.

Comment: it's Sounds strange, why don't you try this syntax instead for your's?


 $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'
    ])->user();


    // stroing data to our use table and logging them in
    $data = [
        'name' => $user->getName(),
        'first_name' => $user->getName(),
        'email' => $user->getEmail()
    ];

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 5.2 and socialite 2.0 .
Then you would face this issue. It's a bug in socialite.
Replace it with the code given below .
Path : vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\

`https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php`
Then below code would provide you complete details
`return Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender', 'birthday'
        ])->scopes([
            'email', 'user_birthday'
        ])->redirect();`

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add more permissions to whatever data you want from Facebook object about your user[image]
facebook api [url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)